# Spring HATEOAS - Mapping EntityModel back to JPA Entities

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

I've mapped the JPA Entity (`User`) to the EntityModel (`UserDTO`) using an extension of `RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<User, UserDTO>` class.

```java
@Override
public UserDTO toModel(@NotNull User user) {
    UserDTO userModel = instantiateModel(user);
    userModel.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    ...
    return userModel;
}
```

Now I'd like to receive UserDTO in a POST request and "convert"/map it back to JPA Entity (User). Is there an inverse of `RepresentationModelAssembler` in Spring?
If there isn't, should I create an additional DTO for the user input? And if so, where should I place the conversion code if not an `Assembler` class?

Comment: check if you have toEntity() method

Comment: Unfortunately not